# Set password to meteor's mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have deployed a meteor project in a stage server and 2 days ago I found out mongodb had no password. I was able to connect to mongodb with robomongo by only providing the IP(no username, no password).

I want to set a password to protect it. I have been following this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) but I get "mongo/mongod not a command" when writing these commands in application's root directory or after "meteor mongo" command.

What am I missing here, how can I protect mongodb with a password?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, when you are running Meteors built-in MongoDB server.

The reason for this is that if you put a password on that database, Meteor will not be able to connect to it.

And to specify a password in the MongoDB connection you need to set the MONGO_URL environment variable.

And when you do that Meteor will think you are running an external MongoDB installation and it will not even start the built-in MongoDB server.

So it's kind of catch-22.

To set a password you need to have a separate MongoDB installed on your server, set a password on that one, and then tell Meteor to use it using a MONGO_URL environment variable in the format:

```
mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/meteor
```

See https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_url

Comment: Thank you for you answer this is very helpful. I will have look at you suggestion :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again JesperWe, I have not used mongodb out of meteor. What is the easiest way to install mongoDB separately and give a password to it. I am familiar with MONGO_URL but not with mongo installation. I see installation process has a ton of commands https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as an answer because it is impossible to format text in a comment, it makes it very hard to read.

I assume you are running on an Amazon linux server, then.

If you really read the install instructions you linked to, you will see that it is not a ton of commands at all.

Install 1: Create the `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo` file with the content given.

Install 2: `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org`

Run: `sudo service mongod start`

Done! MongoDB is now running and listening to port 27017.

You can now add a password, and set MONGO_URL as above.