# MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.100.2:9001] on first connect - Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor Application. I am trying to deploy my application by the custom deployment procedure (on my local machine) by following this article:

https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

But I am facing this error when I run the application via node:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.100.2:9001] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.100.2:9001]
    at Object.wait (/home/martini-henry/myapp-build/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:210:27)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:99:40)
    at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
    at AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
    at server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
    - - - - -
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/martini-henry/myapp-build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/martini-henry/myapp-build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/martini-henry/myapp-build/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

**Steps I performed:**

First I came into the Meteor App directory and ran:

```
meteor build ../myapp-build --architecture os.linux.x86_64
```

Then I provided me the myapp.tar.gz and I extracted that.

**Than I did:**

```
- cd programs/server && npm install
- export MONGO_URL='mongodb://martini-henry:123456@192.168.100.2:9001/myappdb'
- export ROOT_URL='http://192.168.100.2:9000'
```

**And at last when I ran:**

```
- cd ../.. node main.js
```

I got that error above. What could be wrong here? Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Check what port your MongoDB is running on.. The default port is 27017 and you are hardcoded to port 9001 according to your logic above.

Comment: I ran with 27017 port and now I am getting Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment

Comment: Just to confirm, you updated: export MONGO_URL='mongodb://martini-henry:123456@192.168.100.2:9001/myappdb' with export MONGO_URL='mongodb://martini-henry:123456@192.168.100.2:27017/myappdb' and got that error? Have you confirmed your MongoDB is up and running?

Comment: @SteveB yes I ran service mongod status, and it says active

Comment: Now I ran export MONGO_URL='mongodb://martini-henry:123456@localhost:27017/myappdb', it fixed the previous error, but now I am getting: MongoError: Authentication failed.

Comment: The most obvious issue is you have a username and password required for MongoDB, you'll have to supply the password either read from Environment or config file. Hopefully it's that simple.

Comment: @SteveB Can you help me how can I set these username and passowrd for mongodb? I am new to all this

Comment: you can find the answer to add a username and password to your environment variable @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193491/set-password-to-meteors-mongo-database?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa    the format is mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/meteor